# How do I include a complicated University history on my CV?

Tags: resume

I am trying to get my CV together. I know from experience that I don't want it to be more than a single page.

I have a lot of great work experience to include. My school history on the other hand is not great. I have gone to multiple universities and have yet to complete my degree (But I am close).

I have no problem being up front in person about my schooling, but I don't want my CV messy with school experience when my real value comes from work experience. At the same time, I don't feel like anyone will look twice at a resume with no schooling and no degree.

**How can I include some information about my schooling, but make sure that it takes a back seat to my work experience?**

Comment: Uni History, what does that mean?

Comment: List your work experience first

Comment: @MisterPositive I have gone to many universities without getting a degree.

Comment: Simply down the bottom type **U Mich B Sc 49 cr. 2011, Sorbonne M A 78 cr. 2012, UCLA B Sc 82 cr. 2012** with a newline between each (or maybe just one one line like that.  Nothing to fuss about.  It will only be glanced at.

Comment: @Fattie You should put that in an answer IMHO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ONLY university that a prospective employer cares about is the one that issued or is issuing your degree.

On your CV/resume, put something like:

> **Bachelor of Science**
>   ***Underwater Basketweaving***
>
> University of Poor Life Choices  (May, 2018, Expected)

And that's it. If you want to discuss it with a potential employer, that's up to you and it can be done in the interview, but unless you have a degree from a school or are graduating from there, there is no need to make a mess of your CV. Of course, if you've already graduated, the date will be in the past and you should leave off the "Expected"

Now, if you took classes beyond your degree, want to convey that, and have no intention of completing the degree simply put the years you attended like so:

> **Graduate Coursework**
>   ***Underwater Basketweaving***
>
> University of Eternal Debt  (Attended May, 2018 through June, 2020)

Of course, including this kind of educational experience can be a double-edged sword, it shows that you have education beyond your undergraduate degree, but it also brings up the question of why you didn't finish the program, so you should be prepared to answer. It's also OK to leave it off and only bring it up if you feel the need.

Comment: You know, it's incredibly common in computing to just have "BSc, UBig 2013 inc" (with "inc" meaning "incomplete").  I mean, that's what Steve Jobs and Bill Gates have.

Comment: So you're implying that just putting the expected date of graduation should be enough? I didn't think of that but it makes sense. Would I better off putting `May 2018 (Expected)` or something of the like?

Comment: If the date is in the future, "expected" is already implied. I don't think adding it is necessary, nor is it a bad thing.

Comment: @ItsComplicated An explicit "(expected)", "(planned)" or "(in progress)" would be best IMO - without it, even if it's future-dated, a quick glance may make it seem like you have completed it, which might make you come across as deceptive.

Comment: Also relevant: [How to put education on your resume that you have not yet completed?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/37223/how-to-put-education-on-your-resume-that-you-have-not-yet-completed)

Comment: At my university we were encouraged to write "expected" because it is unambiguous and eliminates the possibility that you do have a degree and just made a typo.

Comment: @2rs2ts I can't argue with that. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 3):

What about simply putting this down at the bottom:

> U Mich B Sc 49 cr. 2011
>       Sorbonne M A 78 cr. 2012
>       UCLA B Sc 82 cr. 2012

(or maybe just on one line with commas).

Nothing to fuss about. It will only be glanced at.

I learned this from my friend K who is an absolute master of CVs. On his own he puts after his other degrees  `PhD UCLA 2002 Abd` as he didn't quite finish that one. (Perhaps many glancing at it would assume "abd" is some fancy addendum :) )

(*) Note that, unfortunately really, many QA on this site are from those in the software "industry", I rather assume that's the case with you, OP.  In software other than in some niches, in most regions nobody cares much about your education other than nominally.  Obviously if you work in a more grown-up profession, you may need to take more care. But the above is fine if you want to make web pages, the next gem attack thumbcandy, etc.

Comment: An effective way to handle it IMHO

Answer (score 2):

Having myself transferred twice and subsequently graduated, I was told throughout my acadmeic career to include each University I attended and my major and minor at each one.  However every perspective employer has been confused by this, and unanimously advised that I only include the school from which I graduated and/or was slated to graduate from. It could vary based on location, but I suggest that you include only the school that will issue your degree, and only the Major that you will be graduating with.

Comment: +1 this is a good option. If any of the schools are of note, maybe include it otherwise just stick with the uni you will graduate from, with the expected graduation month and year, and the major/minor you will receive from that school.